# How to make TextArea unclickable in desktop application(JAVA)?

Tags: java

I am making a desktop app. in Java. In which, a person will first browse a pdf or txt and then its content will be displayed in the TextArea. So, i want that no one can edit the content in TextArea. So, how can we make TextArea unclickable, when a person clicks on a browse button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new JTextField or JTextArea

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("Read Only JTextField Example"); // for JTextArea: JTextArea field = new JTextArea();
```

To make JTextField read only or non editable use, void setEditable(boolean editable) method with false argument.

```
field.setEditable(false);
```